# Kafka Spring: How to write unit tests for ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory and ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer?

Tags: spring-kafka

I have 2 classes; 1 for the factories and the other for listener containers:

```
public class ConsumerFactories() {
@Bean
  public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Byte[]> adeKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Byte[]> factory = null;
    factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Byte[]>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory1());
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory2());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
    return factory;
  }
}
```

And my listener class has multiple containers:

```
@Bean
  public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, byte[]> adeListenerContainer() throws BeansException, ClassNotFoundException {
    final ContainerProperties containerProperties =
        new ContainerProperties("topic1");
    containerProperties.setMessageListener(new MessageListener<String, byte[]>() {
      @Override
      public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record) {
        System.out.println("Thread is: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      }
    });

    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, byte[]> container =
        new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory1, containerProperties);
    container.setBeanName("bean1");
    container.setConcurrency(60);
    container.start();
    return container;
  }


@Bean
  public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, byte[]> adeListenerContainer() throws BeansException, ClassNotFoundException {
    final ContainerProperties containerProperties =
        new ContainerProperties("topic1");
    containerProperties.setMessageListener(new MessageListener<String, byte[]>() {
      @Override
      public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record) {
        System.out.println("Thread is: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      }
    });

    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, byte[]> container =
        new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory2, containerProperties);
    container.setBeanName("bean2");
    container.setConcurrency(60);
    container.start();
    return container;
  }
```

1) How can I write unit tests for these 2 classes and methods?

2) Since all my listener containers are doing the same processing work but for a different set of topics, can I pass the topics when I'm setting consumerFactory or any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

> `container.start();`

Never `start()` components in bean definitions - the application context is not ready yet; the container will automatically start the containers at the right time (as long as `autoStartup` is true (default).

2. Why do you need a container factory if you are creating the containers youself?

It's not clear what you want to test.

**EDIT**

Here's an example of programmatically registering containers, using Spring Boot's auto-configured container factory (2.2 and above)...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So53752783Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So53752783Application.class, args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Bean
    public SmartInitializingSingleton creator(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory,
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory) {
        return () -> Stream.of("foo", "bar", "baz").forEach(topic -> {
            ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = factory.createContainer(topic);
            container.getContainerProperties().setMessageListener((MessageListener<String, String>) record -> {
                System.out.println("Received " + record);
            });
            container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId(topic + ".group");
            container = (ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>)
                    beanFactory.initializeBean(container, topic + ".container");
            beanFactory.registerSingleton(topic + ".container", container);
            container.start();
        });
    }

}
```

To unit test your listener,

```
container.getContainerProperties().getMessagelistener()
```

cast it and invoke `onMessage()` and verify it did what you expected.

**EDIT2 Unit Testing the listener**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So53752783Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So53752783Application.class, args);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Bean
    public SmartInitializingSingleton creator(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory,
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory,
            MyListener listener) {

        return () -> Stream.of("foo", "bar", "baz").forEach(topic -> {
            ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = factory.createContainer(topic);
            container.getContainerProperties().setMessageListener(listener);
            container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId(topic + ".group");
            container = (ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>)
                    beanFactory.initializeBean(container, topic + ".container");
            beanFactory.registerSingleton(topic + ".container", container);
            container.start();
        });
    }

    @Bean
    public MyListener listener() {
        return new MyListener();
    }

    public static class MyListener implements MessageListener<String, String> {

        @Autowired
        private Service service;

        public void setService(Service service) {
            this.service = service;
        }


        @Override
        public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> data) {
            this.service.callSomeService(data.value().toUpperCase());
        }

    }

    public interface Service {

        void callSomeService(String in);

    }

    @Component
    public static class DefaultService implements Service {

        @Override
        public void callSomeService(String in) {
            // ...
        }

    }

 }
```

and

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class So53752783ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<?, ?> container = context.getBean("foo.container",
                ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.class);
        MyListener messageListener = (MyListener) container.getContainerProperties().getMessageListener();
        Service service = mock(Service.class);
        messageListener.setService(service);
        messageListener.onMessage(new ConsumerRecord<>("foo", 0, 0L, "key", "foo"));
        verify(service).callSomeService("FOO");
    }

}
```

Comment: I was using the container factory to pass the configurations. Do you suggest I do it some other way?

Comment: I don't see you using `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` anywhere in the container definitions so I don't know what you mean by "pass the configuration". Starting with version 2.2, you can use `containerFactory.createContainer("topic")` to create any arbitrary container factory.

Comment: Thanks Gary! I removed the ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory part and included everything in the lister container. Can listener containers be created dynamically in a loop with different topics list?

Comment: You can, but you have to satisfy all the `...Aware` interfaces and perform Spring Bean management operations (`InitializingBean`, `Lifecycle` etc), or use `beanFactory.initializeBean` and register them as singletons with the bean factory.

Comment: Okay. I'll look into that. How can I unit test the listener container part? I'm setting the listener inside it

Comment: Again, it's not clear what you mean by "test the container"; you would unit test a listener; if you mean an integration test where you send a message to Kafka and expect it to be received by the listener, you can use an Embedded Kafka broker in your integration tests. See the project documentation.

Comment: I meant testing the listener actually. Sorry, I wasn't clear. Also, do you have any code examples for dynamic listener containers creation? We have a lot of topics and we'd want a container for each but manually creating them all is time-consuming.

Comment: I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Hi Gary, can you add an example for unit test, please? It throws an NPE when I try to do what you suggested.